# Issue with phpseclib sha256 verification

Tags: cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, phpseclib

I am having trouble using phpseclib to verify the signature used in the example documented in appendix A.2.2 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-38.  The values used as modulus, exponent, signature and tobesigned come from the appendix of the specification.  The signature does verify when using .NET and several implementations of the specification have been created so it I assume the inputs are valid. I have no previous experience with phpseclib, had to guess at how to load the key, and find the documentation minimalistic so your help would be much appreciated!

```
// per guzmar converts the encoding used in the ietf specification to a string
function cpim_base64url_decode($data) { 
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, 
            '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 
} 

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$publicKeyUrlEncoded = "ofgWCuLjybRlzo0tZWJjNiuSfb4p4fAkd_wWJcyQoTbji9k0l8W26mPddxHmfHQp-Vaw-4qPCJrcS2mJPMEzP1Pt0Bm4d4QlL-yRT-SFd2lZS-pCgNMsD1W_YpRPEwOWvG6b32690r2jZ47soMZo9wGzjb_7OMg0LOL-bSf63kpaSHSXndS5z5rexMdbBYUsLA9e-KXBdQOS-UTo7WTBEMa2R2CapHg665xsmtdVMTBQY4uDZlxvb3qCo5ZwKh9kG4LT6_I5IhlJH7aGhyxXFvUK-DWNmoudF8NAco9_h9iaGNj8q2ethFkMLs91kzk2PAcDTW9gb54h4FRWyuXpoQ";
$exponentUrlEncoded = "AQAB";
$publicKeyString = base64url_decode($publicKeyUrlEncoded);
$exponentString = base64url_decode($exponentUrlEncoded);

$pk = array(
   'e' => new Math_BigInteger($exponentString, -256),
   'n' => new Math_BigInteger($publicKeyString, -256)
);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

$tobesignedString   = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ';
$signatureUrlEncoded = "cC4hiUPoj9Eetdgtv3hF80EGrhuB__dzERat0XF9g2VtQgr9PJbu3XOiZj5RZmh7AAuHIm4Bh-0Qc_lF5YKt_O8W2Fp5jujGbds9uJdbF9CUAr7t1dnZcAcQjbKBYNX4BAynRFdiuB--f_nZLgrnbyTyWzO75vRK5h6xBArLIARNPvkSjtQBMHlb1L07Qe7K0GarZRmB_eSN9383LcOLn6_dO--xi12jzDwusC-eOkHWEsqtFZESc6BfI7noOPqvhJ1phCnvWh6IeYI2w9QOYEUipUTI8np6LbgGY9Fs98rqVt5AXLIhWkWywlVmtVrBp0igcN_IoypGlUPQGe77Rw"; 
$signatureString = base64url_decode($signatureUrlEncoded);

$keyloadResult = $rsa->loadKey($pk, CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);

$result = $rsa->verify($tobesignedString, $signatureString) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

Comment: To be clearer about the specific problem:  the signature should verify but it does not

Comment: Is the `n` component possibly negative?

Comment: Yes the `n` is negative.

Comment: Ah, so that means that the calculation will fail. You should add a zero valued byte in front (the left) of at least the modulus and the private exponent.

Comment: Thanks so much Maarten.  That solved the problem.  Does that mean I should always test whether the high order bit is set and if so add a zero valued byte?  Do other implementations analogous to "loadkey" do this automatically?  Finally is it possible to explain why negatives makes the calculation fail or should this be obvious??  Thanks again.

Comment: @KimCameron - maybe you should do `new Math_BigInteger($exponentString, 256)`, with a positive 256, instead of -256.

Comment: I've removed my comments to you neubert. Please do the same. If you have additional questions or an answer, you are free to create a post yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `n` and possibly the private exponent are negative.

Modular arithmetic doesn't work with a negative modulus. It depends on the library if this is a problem. The crypto-specific BN_ libs of OpenSSL are only for positive values, but other libraries that use a two complement implementation - i.e. with negative values such as Java have the same issues.

You could just always prefix a zero valued byte for any number used within RSA. RSA is based on modular arithmetic and doesn't use negative values for any of the components of a key.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library. In my opinion - as `$pk` already contains the negative number - the library function should error and bail out. Just "fixing" the input is not the way to go, rather create something that is "fail fast". Anything still missing from the answer?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can hit the accept button which is the V button on the left of the answer. Try not to leave answered questions open; either follow up with a comment or accept. You don't *have* to accept, but it is recommended to show the question has been solved (and you can change afterwards, if that's needed). It's probably best to include the code required so others can try - otherwise link to the right API function or standard. Oh, and welcome of course :)